# Saving files in current directory

Tags: java, io

I've been searching for this and many answers came out but it just wasn't the solution I was looking for so I came here and try to ask help to you guys...

I want to create a `.txt` file in the same folder where the JAR file is located  (dist folder)...

I tried using `System.getProperty("user.dir")` it works fine when I run it on windows and using netbeans the file created is always in the same folder where the jar file is but when I run it on LINUX it saves the file in root... but the folder where the jar file is on the desktop

it creates in the same folder when I use the terminal to open the jar file

```
private static String directory=System.getProperty("user.dir");
private final String sample=directory+File.separator+"sample.txt";


public void createFile()
{
     File file=new File(sample);
    try(FileWriter fw=new FileWriter(file))
    {
        fw.write("INSERT ME WHERE MY JAR IS");
        fw.flush();
        fw.close();
    }catch(IOException ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: already did that but it didn't work...

Answer (score 10):

You can refer to your working directory with

```
File directory = new File(".")
```

and you can access a file on it using

```
System.getProperty(directory.getCanonicalPath() + File.separator + "my.properties")
```

OR

```
System.getProperty("." + File.separator + "my.properties")
```

The "." refers to your current directory. The use of `File.separator` ensures your get '/' in UNIX-based file systems and "\" in NTFS.

Comment: ok i'll try it, does this work both on WINDOWS and LINUX?

Comment: Yep it's valid for both...

Comment: hmm it returns a blank

Comment: Returns a blank what?

Comment: sorry miscode but I did it and it still creates file in root

Comment: +1 for ".".
The "." to refer to the working directory is better than System.getProperty("user.dir"); because say we need to save the path of a saved-in-current-working-dir file somewhere, in case the user changes the JAR file place, and later if  we try to retrieve it, a FileNotFoundException will be thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Had same problem: These will work for **LINUX**

**Current directory's canonical path:** `directory.getCanonicalPath());`

**Current directory's absolute  path:** `directory.getAbsolutePath());`

If it varies in windows try to check for OS and run code:
Like

```
System.getProperty("os.name");
```

Or else Use:

```
String absolutePath = getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();
        absolutePath = absolutePath.substring(0, absolutePath.lastIndexOf("/"));
```

Comment: directory? what is that is that a variable sir? sorry, still not getting used to all these

Comment: File directory = new File ("."); The file which you create

Comment: see my edit u can find the absolute path in string (both in windows and linux)